# How to add page argument in hook_menu for dynamic callback function?

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm using groups for my website and I would like to create functions that will work for every group.
I've created a tab configuration for every group like this.

```
$groups = group_load_by_type('community');
foreach($groups as $key => $value) {
  $items[CONFIG_GLOBAL_ADMIN_PATH . '/groups/' . $key] = array(
    'title' => $value->title,
    'description' => 'Group ' . $value->title,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('myModule_group_settings_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file' => 'myModule_group.admin.inc',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 1,
  );
}
```

It's working pretty well this way, I have the config for all the groups at the `path/groups/groupID` which is what I want.

But I would like to add an argument to my function `myModule_group_setting_form($form, &$form_state)` and do something like this:

```
'page arguments' => array('myModule_group_settings_form', $key->title),
```

and change my function to this :

```
myModule_group_setting_form($form, &$form_state, $groupName)
```

In my function, I'm using variables so the groups can hide some informations if they want.
Actually if I want to do this, I have to create a function for every group and do something like this :

```
'page arguments' => array('myModule_group_' . $key->title . '_settings_form'
```

And I have to create a new function every time I have a new group. Since I don't have static groups, and I may have to create others in the future, this way doesn't suits me.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. You mean Organic groups? And what exactly is the question?

Comment: Thanks. No just the "Group" module. I want to give an argument to my function in the 'page argument' but i don't find a way to do as i wish. I've written an example of what i would like to do but it appears i'ts not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new menu for new group. It will be better to use dynamic arguments.

```
$items[CONFIG_GLOBAL_ADMIN_PATH . '/groups/%'] = array(
  'description' => 'Some Group Description',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('myModule_group_settings_form', 3),
  'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  'file' => 'myModule_group.admin.inc',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 1,
);
```

and In your function :

```
function myModule_group_setting_form($form, &$form_state, $key) {
  $groups = group_load_by_type('community');
  $value = (isset($groups[$key])) ? $groups[$key] : NULL;
  if (!$value) {
    drupal_set_title($value->title);
    // Whatever you do with $value->title;
  }
  else {
    drupal_not_found(); exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well i tried your solution but had an error at the $value=$groups[$key], drupal tells me i have an undefined index on groups. So i tried to cast $key as an int but have an undefinied offset at 0(which is true), but if i tell $groups[2] it's alright. However, i don't understand how drupal will create all the tabs for all the groups on the config page if the research is done inside the function. Actually i need to have an argument to generate the page.

Comment: It means no item exists with that key.

Comment: @see my edit too. Well i understand that, but the thing is if i change le last argument of the url address (/groups/2, /groups/3, ...) it doesn't change anything whether the number is correct or incorrect.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Well i do understand what you meant with this modification. However, i have no pages that works, it's like if the /groupID is useless and will always be set to 0 (which is why i have an undefined index since i have no group with the id 0).
I still have the same question remaining. How will drupal display my group tabs on the config page if it is check in the function ? With my old method i create a tab whenever i have a community group type.

Comment: Well, you can render your custom html which looks like the tabs. No??

Comment: I'm not really sure, i'm using the classical theme for all the administration part, i only have a custom theme for the website that will be displayed to people. Even if i create a custom theme i will have to check whether the group is a community or not before displaying the tab (as i was doing before) and i will check another time inside the function, it's not really efficient to me.
Now i know the problem, whatever the argument is in the 'page arguments', i will always have 'groups' returned. I changed the path to /groups1 and i had group1 returned. Do you know why ?

Comment: Oh then change 3 to 4 in `page arguments`.

Comment: Oh well, i'm such a retard :(
I tried from -1 to 5 before but forgot to delete the cache between  2 changes.
Now i just need to find a cool way to display the tabs and i'll be done :)
Thank you for your help and patience :)